# UI-Router - Basic url mismatch

Tags: angular-ui-router

All states work well from one to the other, but I have some issues with refreshing them :

refreshing `/products/verandas` leads to `/warranty/verandas`

refreshing `/products/pergolas` leads to `/warranty/pergolas-inside`

```
.state('app', {              // LEVEL 0
    abstract: true, 
    url: ''
})
.state('app.posts', {        // LEVEL 1  -> this parent is defined
    url: '/products',        //             but not prioritized on refresh
})
.state('app.posts.type', {   // LEVEL 2
    url: '/{type}',
})

.state('app.page', {         // LEVEL 1
    url: '/{level1}',
    abstract: true
})
.state('app.page.child', {   // LEVEL 2
    url: '/{level2}',
})
```

Any help is welcome...

Johan

Comment: Can you share the definition of state 'app' ?

Comment: Hi Mathews, i have added the definitition of 'app', which is just an abstract one to load a main controller, and a main view.   Let me know if you need more details on the states to understand the case.

Comment: Can you change the def of state 'app' to this and check? .state('app', {              
    abstract: true, url: ''
})

Comment: Thanx for trying, but no success...